# Asp.net MVC RouteBase and IoC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, structuremap, ioc-container

I am creating a custom route by subclassing RouteBase. I have a dependency in there that I'd like to wire up with IoC. The method GetRouteData just takes HttpContext, but I want to add in my unit of work as well....somehow.

I am using StructureMap, but info on how you would do this with any IoC framework would be helpful.

Comment: Could you please give a bit more info on what are you trying to achieve? Because the `Route` class doesn't seem to be a good place for dependency. You mentioned UoW, so I think you are going to get something from DB. I'm just wondering why `Route`.

Comment: kinda like a cms....loading up data for a page and adding it into route data. It's working quite well, just want to clean up the dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here is our solution. Many little details may be omitted but overall idea is here. This answer may be a kind of offtop to original question but it describes the general solution to the problem.

I'll try to explain the part that is responsible for plain custom HTML-pages that are created by users at runtime and therefore can't have their own Controller/Action. So the routes should be either somehow built at runtime or be "catch-all" with custom IRouteConstraint.

First of all, lets state some facts and requirements.

- We have some data and some metadata about our pages stored in DB;
- We don't want to generate a (hypothetically) whole million of routes for all of existing pages beforehand (i.e. on Application startup) because something can change during application and we don't want to tackle with pushing the changes to global RouteCollection;

So we do it this way:

### 1. PageController

Yes, special controller that is responsible for all our content pages. And there is the only action that is `Display(int id)` (actually we have a special ViewModel as param but I used an `int id` for simplicity.

The page with all its data is resolved by ID inside that `Display()` method. The method itself returns either `ViewResult` (strongly typed after `PageViewModel`) or `NotFoundResult` in case when page is not found.

### 2. Custom IRouteConstraint

We have to somewhere define if the URL user actually requested refers to one of our custom pages. For this we have a special `IsPageConstraint` that implements `IRouteConstraint` interface. In the `Match()` method of our constraint we just call our `PageRepository` to check whether there is a page that match our requested URL. We have our PageRepository injected by StructureMap. If we find the page then we add that "id" parameter (with the value) to the RouteData dictionary and it is automatically bound to `PageController.Display(int id)` by `DefaultModelBinder`.

But we need a RouteData parameter to check. Where we get that? Here comes...

### 3. Route mapping with "catch-all" parameter

Important note: this route is defined in the very end of route mappings list because it is very general, not specific. We check all our explicitly defined routes first and then check for a `Page` (that is easily changeable if needed).

We simply map our route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("ContentPages", 
                "{*pagePath}", 
                new { controller = "Page", action = "Display" }
                new { pagePath = new DependencyRouteConstraint<IsPageConstraint>() });
```

Stop! What is that `DependencyRouteConstraint` thing appeared in mapping? Well, thats what does the trick.

### 4. DependencyRouteConstraint<TConstraint> class

This is just another generic implementation of `IRouteConstraint` which takes the **"real"** `IRouteConstraint` (IsPageConstraint) and resolves it (the given `TConstraint`) only when `Match()` method called. It uses dependency injection so our `IsPageConstraint` instance has all actual dependencies injected!

Our `DependencyRouteConstraint` then just calls the `dependentConstraint.Match()` providing all the parameters thus just delegating actual "matching" to the "real" IRouteConstraint.

Note: this class actually has the dependency on ServiceLocator.

### Summary

That way we have:

- Our `Route` clear and clean;
- The only class that has a dependency on Service Locator is `DependencyRouteConstraint`;
- Any custom `IRouteConstraint` uses dependency injection whenever needed;
- ???
- PROFIT!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I am essentially doing the same thing, however my route checks to see if the user is requesting a custom page, if not it returns null and falls through to the default mvc route. In my case if it is a custom page, I am loading up the page data and adding the resulting view model into route data, rather than just the page id like you are. Wouldn't you agree that what we are doing is not all that different? I mean, we both need one usage of a service locator.

Comment: Sure, you can add any other data not just page ID if you want. The difference, as I see it is that we don't change the `Route` class for this but use `IRouteConstraint` instead which seems just a more appropriate place for those checks. For us, `Route` is just a mapping-data carrier class. It knows nothing about our "Pages" or whatever (which is always a good thing because doesn't violate SRP and leave things decoupled enough).

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is:

- **Route** must be defined beforehand, during Application startup
- **Route**'s responsibility is to map the incoming URL pattern to the right Controller/Action to perform some task on request. And visa versa - to generate links using that mapping data. Period. Everything else is "Single Responsibility Principle" violation which actually led to your problem.
- But **UoW** dependencies (like NHibernate ISession, or EF ObjectContext) must be resolved at runtime.

And that is why I don't see the children of RouteBase class as a good place for some DB work dependency. It makes everything closely coupled and non-scalable. It is actually impossible to perform Dependency Injection.

From now (I guess there is some kind of already working system) you actually have just one more or less viable option that is:

- To use Service Locator pattern: resolve your **UoW** instance right inside the GetRouteData method (use [CommonServiceLocator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) backed by StructureMap IContainer). That is simple but not really nice thing because this way you get the dependency on static Service Locator itself in your `Route`.

With CSL you have to just call inside `GetRouteData`:

```
var uow = ServiceLocator.Current.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();
```

or with just StructureMap (without CSL facade):

```
var uow = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
```

and you're done. Quick and dirty. And the keyword is "dirty" actually :)

Sure, there is much more flexible solution but it needs a few architectural changes. If you provide more details on exactly what data you get in your routes I can try to explain how we solved our `Pages` routing problem (using DI and custom `IRouteConstraint`).

Comment: Sure, please elaborate on your solution if you can. We get all html/links/etcs for a given page and store it in RouteData. Basically all of the content you'd see on a webpage.

Comment: Obviosly, Html, links and other **Page** data should not belong to RouteData. At least because `Route` and `Page` have different lifetimes. I'll try to explain our solution as a separate answer.